# Lambda expression myimage.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(imagebytes));

Tags: c#, lambda

I have copied this line from a Google search.

```
myimage.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(imagebytes));
```

It works perfectly.

However, I am new to C# and I don't understand what this line of code is doing.

Could someone translate it into English for me please as I am an antique VB.Net programmer.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, what you do with this code, is:

1.) You take some bytes (byte array the image is converted to)

2.) Build up a `MemoryStream` object with this bytes array as buffer (source)

3.) Build up a `ImageSource` object via shared member function `FromStream` (this takes a `delegate` - i.e.  a function that returns `Stream` or something derived of `Stream`, a lamda expression that returns some `Stream` (derivate) - and executes it

4.) Assign this to your `myimage.Source`

Comment: Ah so the lamda expression returns a stream whereas ImageSource.FromStream() would not accept a memorystream. Thank goodness for Google (somedays).

Comment: Not really: the lamda function returns a MemoryStream object. Since FromStream() wants a function, that returns a Stream(inherited object), you can return a Stream, FileStream, StreamWriter, MemoryStream,... 2beshort: Everything that has Stream in its inheritance path. But since creating a reading stream from a output-only stream it is no good idea to return a StreamWriter but a MemoryStream